# YCSB Maven build error

Tags: java, git, maven, hadoop

I cloned [YSCB git](http://github.com/brianfrankcooper/YCSB.git) and modified pom.xml in `\hbase` folder for pointing to right version of my HBase and Hadoop. After that, I was trying to make YCSB package using `mvn clean package', but I get following errors which I'm not able to resolve.

```
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building HBase DB Binding 0.1.4
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The POM for org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-core:jar:2.4.0 is missing, no dependency information available
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO]
[INFO] YCSB Root .......................................... SUCCESS [  0.954 s]
[INFO] Core YCSB .......................................... SUCCESS [ 19.117 s]
[INFO] Cassandra DB Binding ............................... SUCCESS [ 10.728 s]
[INFO] HBase DB Binding ................................... FAILURE [  0.260 s]
[INFO] Hypertable DB Binding .............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Accumulo DB Binding ................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] DynamoDB DB Binding ................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] ElasticSearch Binding .............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Infinispan DB Binding .............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] JDBC DB Binding .................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Mapkeeper DB Binding ............................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Mongo DB Binding ................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] OrientDB Binding ................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Redis DB Binding ................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Voldemort DB Binding ............................... SKIPPED
[INFO] YCSB Release Distribution Builder .................. SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 31.309 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-02-27T08:30:30+00:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 53M/934M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project hbase-binding: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.yahoo.ycsb:hbase-binding:jar:0.1.4: Failure to find org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-core:jar:2.4.0 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
[ERROR]
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :hbase-binding
```

I'm using HBase version 0.94.18 & Hadoop 2.4.0. Any suggestions on how to resolve it?

Comment: try `mvn clean install -U`

Comment: Hadoop 2.4.0 is not in Central and `com.yahoo.ycsb:hbase-binding` is also not in central.. This causes your problems. You have to configure your repository manager to use the appropriate repository to get your build working.

Comment: @Mr.Chowdary I don't want to install. I need package. Will that command help me in creating package as well?

Anyways, did that and still I see same error. :|

Comment: @khmarbaise How do I configure it? I mean which tag in pom.xml & ion which directory I've to modify it?

Answer (score 0):

Have you changed the hbase and hadoop versions in the hbase pom.xml file. 
Also check whether the required jar is available at the repository you have used https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2

If you are using YCSB only for hbase i would suggest removing the unwanted modules from the pom file this will reduce the time taken to build.

Comment: It is not the time, which was causing the issue. It the failure!